# How can I restore my Mist wallet if I forgot password?[Windows]

Tags: mist, wallets

Lets say, I have Mist on Windows, but I cannot remember what password I used for my wallet there. However, I am almost sure that it is some of passwords I usually use or their combination(like pass1+pass2, or even pass1+pass2+pass3). I tried pyethrecover, but it seems to be broken, also it requires to install python, but I don't want too install anything. 
So how can I restore my password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed app for such case. It takes passwords you gave to it, and then combines them by two(it also uses CAPSLOCK version of these passwords for case when entered capclocked version but haven't noticed it). Then it passes all genreted passwords to geth, one by one, and tells you if it found correct password.

You can find more information on github: https://github.com/MaxPovver/TryPasses

I understand that passwords are sensitive information, that is why I give you sources so you can check that nothing is sent anywhere. If you don't want to compile from sources, wou can use first release from this page: https://github.com/MaxPovver/TryPasses/releases

Please ask me if you have any questions